# What is a smarter way to use a single table instance in a query that JOIN 2 times the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem working on a query that do some JOIN and that have to join 2 times the same **Languages** table.

I am using **MySql**. I will try to explain my problem.

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
        LSSN.livestock_species_name AS species_name,
        LSM.content                 AS message_content,
        LSM.audio_link              AS message_audio_link
FROM LivestockDetails AS LSD
INNER JOIN LsMessage AS LSM
      ON LSD.ls_message_id = LSM.id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
      ON LSM.language_id = LNG.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies AS LSS
      ON LSD.live_stock_species_id = LSS.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpeciesName AS LSSN
      ON LSS.id = LSSN.livestock_species_id 
INNER JOIN LNG
      ON LSSN.language_id = LNG.id
WHERE LSD.live_stock_species_id = 3
AND LSD.ls_area_id = 2
AND LSD.ls_action_type_id = 1
AND LSD.ls_message_id is not null
AND LNG.id = 1
```

As you can see I am trying to join 2 times the **Langunages** (aliasted by **LNG**).

Once here (because I have localized messages in a specific langunage):

```
INNER JOIN LsMessage AS LSM
      ON LSD.ls_message_id = LSM.id
```

and another one here (because the **LSSN** table contains the name of an animal in a specific language):

```
INNER JOIN LNG
      ON LSSN.language_id = LNG.id
```

Doing in this way it doesn't work and I am obtain this error message:

```
#42000Not unique table/alias: 'LNG'
```

I think because I am joining 2 times the same table.

I can do it in this way and it works fine:

```
SELECT 
        LSSN.livestock_species_name AS species_name,
        LSM.content                 AS message_content,
        LSM.audio_link              AS message_audio_link
FROM LivestockDetails AS LSD
INNER JOIN LsMessage AS LSM
      ON LSD.ls_message_id = LSM.id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
      ON LSM.language_id = LNG.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies AS LSS
      ON LSD.live_stock_species_id = LSS.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpeciesName AS LSSN
      ON LSS.id = LSSN.livestock_species_id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG2
      ON LSSN.language_id = LNG2.id
WHERE LSD.live_stock_species_id = 3
AND LSD.ls_area_id = 2
AND LSD.ls_action_type_id = 1
AND LSD.ls_message_id is not null
AND LNG.id = LNG2.id = 1
```

I joined with a "brand new" **INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG2** table but then I have to change the **WHERE** clause in this way:

```
AND LNG.id = LNG2.id = 1
```

I am asking if it is a good solution or if exist some smarter way to use a single table instead the **LNG** and **LNG2** tables in the JOIN operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one more way you can achieve what you want:

```
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
    ON LSM.language_id = LNG.id
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG2
    ON LSM.language_id = LNG2.id AND LSSN.language_id = LNG2.id
```

I think you can't merge those 2 joins into 1.

Full query:

```
SELECT 
        LSSN.livestock_species_name AS species_name,
        LSM.content                 AS message_content,
        LSM.audio_link              AS message_audio_link
FROM LivestockDetails AS LSD
INNER JOIN LsMessage AS LSM
      ON LSD.ls_message_id = LSM.id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
      ON LSM.language_id = LNG.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies AS LSS
      ON LSD.live_stock_species_id = LSS.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpeciesName AS LSSN
      ON LSS.id = LSSN.livestock_species_id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG2
    ON LSM.language_id = LNG2.id AND LSSN.language_id = LNG2.id
WHERE LSD.live_stock_species_id = 3
AND LSD.ls_area_id = 2
AND LSD.ls_action_type_id = 1
AND LSD.ls_message_id is not null
AND LNG.id = 1
```

Comment: So what exactly leamsn the AND operator defined on the JOIN statment? Is it something like a double ON condition?

Comment: Exactly that. You don't need to have only 1 comparison in ON.